# How to authenticate if a user "owns" a model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Site(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)

class Team(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    team_member_name = models.CharField(default='name', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
```

I have a view that passes a `team_member` id via the URL:

Urls.py:

```
url(r'^team/(?P<team_member_id>\d+)/$', 'team.views.home', name='team_view_team_member')
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def home(request, team_member_id=None):
    team_member = Team.objects.get(id=team_member_id)
```

**Note that there are many `Team` instances (i.e. lots of team members) which have the same `Site_id`.**

How can I test if the `request.user` has the same `site_id` as any `team_member` returned? Is there a simple way to repeat this if I want to use it across multiple views?

Comment: Try this: `team_member = Team.objects.get(site__user=request.user)` if everything goes ok, it will return a Team object, then with `team_member.team_member_name` you get the member name.

Comment: @Gocht that works if there is only 1 team member with the same site_id, but there are many (it's a one-to-many relationship) - I have clarified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
team_member = Team.objects.get(id=team_member_id)
if team_member.site.id == request.user.site_set.all().first().id:
   print "same site"
else:
   print "different site"
```

Comment: I don't think use indexes is a good idea, use `first()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain the logic behind your code? This results in `'User' object has no attribute 'UserProfile_set'`.

Comment: @alias51 Try with `request.user.user_profile_set...`

Comment: @Gocht thanks, same error: `'User' object has no attribute 'user_profile_set'`

Comment: @Geo thanks, it works with `request.user.site_set.all().first().id:` - can you explain the logic and why we need to use `first()`?

Comment: first() will take the first element of  queryset. Here request.user.site_set.all() this will return a queryset  try print this queryset, then you will get to know the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
# Site for user in request
req_user_site = Site.objects.get(user=request.user)  # Use filter if it will return more than one object

# Site for team member in url
sites = Site.objects.filter(team__pk=team_member_id)

# Then compare
if req_user_site in sites:
    print "have the same"
else:
    print "don't"
```